# Nested loops to find counting numbers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

never thought i had issues with nested loops well here Iam: What i want to achieve is this: Given two number  A and B i need to find all counting numbers between 1 and the A*B for example A=4 B=3 i need this:

```
      1 2 3
      4 5 6
      7 8 9
      10 11 12
```

I wrote the initial parts but i can't figure out how can i write down the value which changes in every row

```
      for(int i=1; i<=A; i++){
                 for(int j=1; j<=B; j++){
                      System.out.println("?");}}
```

Having A*B gives me

```
    1 2 3
    2 4 6
    3 6 9
    4 8 12
```

I tried some other combinations too but to no luck, It might look straight forward but its the first time i'm facing this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about just looping `for (int i = 1; i <= A*B; i++)`?

Comment: Look at the pattern in your desired matrix.  Row 0 starts with 1, row 1 starts with 4, row 2 -> 7, row 3 -> 10.  Come up with a formula to duplicate that and you're halfway there.  Hint: start your loops with 0, not 1. Hint 2: make your formula work in terms of the row number and the value of B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `(i-1)*B + j`.

Another option is to just use 1 for loop:

```
int limit = A * B;
for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    if (i % B == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i=0; i<A; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<B; j++){
        System.out.print(B*i + (j + 1));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: I think this is mathematically sound solution. Small fix, (B(i - 1) + j); should be changed to (B*(i - 1) + j);

Comment: @Serith Thanks for that catch. Fixed. Also switched from looping from 1 to looping from 0. Had copypasta'd OP's source and edited it without realizing that. Prefer base of 0 myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1;i<=A*B;i++)
{  System.out.printf("%d%c",i,(i%B!=0?' ':'\n'));
}
```

---

```
for(i=1;i<A*B;i+=B)
{ for(j=i;j<i+B;j++)
  { System.out.printf("%d ",j);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Question is about **nested** loops.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvoter thought printf wasn't available in Java. The answer can be made more clear by using `System.out.printf`. However, it should be `i%B`.

Comment: @Sam true, but this answer does give the OP a cleaner, one line solution. The OP may not be aware that something like this even exists.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Why it has to be a nested loop? however, this one might work

```
for(int i=0; i < A; i++){
      for(int j=i*B; j<(i+1)*B; j++){
           System.out.print(j+1);
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int i=1; i<=A; i++){
                 for(int j=1; j<=B; j++){
                      System.out.print(B*(i - 1) + j);
                 }
                 System.out.println();
 }
```

Comment: probably shouldn't be using println

Comment: You're right, but I was answering the formula question (edited, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is ridiculously simply, just use one more variable and count it from 1 to A*B.

```
q = 0;
for(int i=0; i<A; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<B; j++){
        q++;
        System.out.print(q + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```